# Call a function when the key "space" is pressed in a window

Tags: wpf

I'm developing a board game and I would like to call a function when <kbd>space</kbd> is pressed in the window but I couldn't find answer to my problem during my searches.
Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this. The easiest is to hook up an event handler (albeit not the most elegant). More elegant solutions involving commands can also be used though, depending on what controls you're using.

XAML

```
<Window KeyDown="MainWindow_OnKeyDown"
        <!-- other properties -->
>
    <!-- rest of your UI -->
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
private void MainWindow_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        // do something  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<Window ...
        PreviewKeyUp="Window_PreviewKeyUp" >


</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
// Use the PreviewKeyUp event to capture the keypress before 
// any child controls that have focus handle the event
private void Window_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        AFunction(); 
        // to prevent the key press to bubble up to child controls that have focus
        e.Handled = true; 
    }
}
```